JBoss 7.4 DB2 Datasource with valid credentials returns -551 SQL error when accessed by application
I have a JBOSS EAP 7.4 instance set up with 2 DB2 Datasources. I have confirmed the credentials are valid and working. I changed them to invalid credentials to ensure I was not getting a false positive with the connection test via management GUI.
The application server starts up fine showing good logs for the Datasource start up and tests but returns Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501 when my application tries to run a query and pull data. Any ideas as to what could cause this?  The error guide for DB2 states this is

-551 auth-id DOES NOT HAVE THE PRIVILEGE TO PERFORM OPERATION operation ON OBJECT object-name
Authorization IDs or roles were checked for authorization to perform an operation on a Db2 object. None of the authorization IDs or roles were authorized to perform the operation.

I expected there to be invalid credentials as a root cause for this -551 SQL error, but I am able to query using those credentials. Additionally, I have a build of this application running with JBOSS EAP 6.4.5 that uses the same credentials and Datasource details, this can pull data successfully. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Talk with your DBA or whoever administers the Db2 databases, there is one or more missing GRANT actions, and/or one or more missing role memberships on the target database. This is not a programming matter, but only a configuration matter on your Db2 database(s).  Compare the authorisations/grants/roles between a working and a failing environment.

Upon looking deeper at what the query was pulling we found a DB view that our userID was not given access too. This solved the issue!
